# Why am I getting the kerberos error "Failed to decrypt AP-REQ ticket"?

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to get SASL + OpenLDAP working over `saslauthd` to AD via *kerberos*. I've fired up `saslauthd` in debug mode and getting the error below in the trace log when I try to `su` to the LDAP account `user101`:

```
[12450] 1605731046.958412: Failed to decrypt AP-REQ ticket: -1765328339/No key table entry found for host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB
```

I can issue `kinit` and there are no complaints about the key table entry. I've launched `saslauthd` this way:

```
export KRB5_KTNAME="/etc/windows.keytab" KRB5_TRACE="/tmp/krb5_trace.log" SOCKETDIR="/var/run/saslauthd" MECHANISMS="kerberos5" ; /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a kerberos5 -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5 -d
```

Any idea why `saslauthd` isn't able to find the key table entry but `kinit` does? I've run across some info about *rc4-hmac* being deprecated and when I remove that from the list of the allowed enctypes in krb5.conf, I get an error that the *KDC has no support for encryption type*. Not sure if that's related to the original error about the key table entry though. Below is some info from the command line and the trace file and krb5.conf:

**keytab princ matches what's being asked for in the trace file**:

```
# kinit -k -t /etc/windows.keytab

# klist -kte
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/windows.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
   3 12/31/1969 18:00:00 host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

**Trace file snippet:**

```
...
[12450] 1605731046.950617: Sending TCP request to stream xxx.xxx.xxx.17:88
[12450] 1605731046.958060: Received answer (1956 bytes) from stream xxx.xxx.xxx.17:88
[12450] 1605731046.958074: Terminating TCP connection to stream xxx.xxx.xxx.17:88
[12450] 1605731046.958131: Response was not from master KDC
[12450] 1605731046.958148: Decoding FAST response
[12450] 1605731046.958196: FAST reply key: aes256-cts/0E58
[12450] 1605731046.958223: TGS reply is for user101@MY.REALM.KRB -> host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB with session key rc4-hmac/ED4E
[12450] 1605731046.958261: TGS request result: 0/Success
[12450] 1605731046.958270: Received creds for desired service host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB
[12450] 1605731046.958277: Storing user101@MY.REALM.KRB -> host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB in MEMORY:0
[12450] 1605731046.958301: Creating authenticator for user101@MY.REALM.KRB -> host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB, seqnum 0, subkey (null), session key rc4-hmac/ED4E
[12450] 1605731046.958402: Retrieving host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB from FILE:/etc/windows.keytab (vno 3, enctype rc4-hmac) with result: -1765328203/No key table entry found for host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB
[12450] 1605731046.958412: Failed to decrypt AP-REQ ticket: -1765328339/No key table entry found for host/ldap-krb-test.mycorp.net@MY.REALM.KRB
[12450] 1605731046.958465: Destroying ccache MEMORY:0
```

**krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
   default_realm = MY.REALM.KRB

   default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
   default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
   permitted_enctypes   = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5

   rdns=false
   dns_lookup_realm = false
   dns_lookup_kdc   = false

[realms]
   MY.REALM.KRB = {
                    kdc          = my.realm.krb
                   admin_server = my.realm.krb
                  }

[domain_realm]
   .my.realm.krb = MY.REALM.KRB
   my.realm.krb  = MY.REALM.KRB
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else, I needed the AD checkbox toggled for *This account supports kerberos AES...* on for the Service account. Everything worked after that:
[image]